# SSRS Report ambiguos behavior Page size Not showing Correctly

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2008-r2

I've created a rdlc report which was working fine.... but then on changing of interacting size of reports it is not showing page sequence given below
[image]

i reverted back the interactive size but still won't fix the major issue....
while printing this convert it to several pages which is fine.
any one guide me where i'm doing wrong..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you try to achieve "page brake",
use this link [page-breaks-in-ssrs-report](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/insert-page-breaks-in-ssrs-report/)

Comment: but before changing Interactive page size, report viewer showing correct behavior of pages... i don't know which of my mistake cause this .....

Comment: Which browser do you use? try explorer or try to change the browser zoom size